# prestashop smarty {$base_dir} multistore

Tags: smarty, prestashop

My website is on Prestashop 1.6 with multistore feature enabled.
When I m in store n°1, I would like to insert a link of store N°2 without having to write the url.
Smarty has the variable {$base_dir} ( URL of the store). The value of this variable change depending the context (if I m in store n°1 or store n°2).
Is there any way to have a smarty variable with which I can get a url of a store in particular?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use :

```
$link->getPageLink($controller, $ssl = null, $id_lang = null, $request = null, $request_url_encode = false, $id_shop = null, $relative_protocol = false).
```

All functions in Link class accept id_shop param. 'index' for IndexController.

Comment: getShopsUrls returns a PrestashopCollection object. I haven't found any method on this objects to return the url of a shop. Link::getPageLink($controller, $ssl = null, $id_lang = null, $request = null, $request_url_encode = false, $id_shop = null, $relative_protocol = false).  Which value for $controller to have the index page of a store?

Comment: I have revise my reply. ask index to have IndexController

Answer (score 0):

I just found this :

```
{assign var="foo" value=Shop::getShops() }
```

It returns an array with the urls of all the shops.

To have the url of shop n°1 :

```
{$foo[1]['uri']}
```

To have the url of shop n°2 :

```
 {$foo[2]['uri']}
```

very easy to use!